# JPA/Eclipselink - select DataSource/JDBC URL dynamically

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, multi-tenant

Is there a way that I can get JPA (Eclipselink specifically) to dynamically select a connection pool depending on some property bound to the current thread?

The problem I'm trying to solve is scaling a multitenant system, where tenants may be split up over several DB instances.  Each DB instance will be multitenant, but to scale, I may not be able to fit all tenants in one DB instance comfortably.

I am familiar with `@Multitenant` to support single-table multitenancy, and have successfully used Eclipselink session event callbacks to set values in the Eclipselink `Session` dynamically.  I'm trying to take the next step of changing the `DataSource` that the EntityManager will be using, so I don't have to necessarily use a clustered DB.

Thanks!

Comment: How many datasources? Can they be initialized at startup or they are too many?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

http://code.google.com/p/jdbc-helper/wiki/LoadBalancingDataSource

It creates a datasource that loadbalances to backend datasources.

Comment: unfortunately i'm not just trying to load balance, I'm trying to explicitly specify a target datasource depending on some attribute of the current request/thread.

Comment: extend LoadBalancingDataSource and override getConnection to select the specific connectionPool from connectionPools based on a threadlocal variable. I haven't worked with the LoadBalancingDataSource so I cannot vouch for its quality.

Comment: Be aware of the Eclipselink shared 2nd level cache, it might get poisoned by inconsistent databases

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `EntitiyManagerFactory` which allows the creation of an `EntitiyManager` for a specific datsasource (via a String property) as explained under

http://foobar.lu/wp/2010/12/30/change-jpa-entitymanager-connection-properties-at-runtime/

Comment: I am using `@PersistenceContext` injection for my `EntityManager` and would like to keep it that way.  I don't want to manage creating and closing EntityManagers in my application code.  If you knew how to do exactly the same thing via EclipseLink session callbacks that would be ideal.

Comment: @wrschneider were you able to get a solution . I am also facing the same scneario and would like to understand if you were able to achieve it using PersistenceContext or Persistence-Unit

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195556/how-to-manage-connections-to-dynamically-created-databases/7195687#7195687). It might be helpful or give you a clue on how to achieve your solution.

Comment: that could work for switching schemas / databases in a single installation/instance, but it would not allow me to dynamically select a host.